# Debug a dependency artifact code using IntelliJ and Apache Tomcat

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, dependencies, tomcat7, artifact

I working with IntelliJ 12 IDE on a Windows 7 machine (64-bit).

I'm running a local Tomcat (configured from IntelliJ) version 7 with war file deployed on it from one of my projects - let's call it project "main".

Debugging project "main" works fine.

Project "main" has a dependency of a different project for filters - let's call it "filter" - which I wrote as well (meaning I have the source code on my machine).

The problem is that I want to set a break point on the "filter" project and debug it as well, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Add it as a module to the first project, configure deployment of both projects to the same server in Tomcat run configuration, this way you'll be able to debug it with no problem.

Comment: can't do, "filter" project is generic and will be used by other teams in the company there for can't change its place.

Comment: You can import modules from any location.

Comment: CrazyCoder thanks for your answers.
Maybe I'm missing something but if I add it as module to the first project and want to include it in another project - projcet third - won't I need to include the whole first project?

Comment: No, you can include modules (stored in .iml files) into multiple projects (stored in .idea directory).

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the filters depency sources to your project, and then you'll be able to put a breakpoint on the filter

Try to do "download sources" of the dependency, if it's not available you need to make them available from the filters project pom.